# Animate div into view with css

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-hooks, css-animations

I am trying to create an animated media gallery. I have a grid of image and when I select an individual image, I would like it to show up at the top as the main image. I would like to animate this with css to give the effect that the main image goes to the top and the other images get 'pushed down' and then, when I close the main image, the other images push back up again.

```css
.image {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.media-grid {
  margin-top: 1rem;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  gap: 10px 10px;
}

.main-image-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 300px;
}

.main-image {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  border: 2px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="main-image-container">
    <div class="main-image">
      Main Image
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="media-grid">
    <div class="image">Image</div>
    <div class="image">Image</div>
    <div class="image">Image</div>
    <div class="image">Image</div>
    <div class="image">Image</div>
    <div class="image">Image</div>
    <div class="image">Image</div>
    <div class="image">Image</div>
    <div class="image">Image</div>
    <div class="image">Image</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I’m on my phone right now so I can’t write code based on what you’re asking but someone is doing something similar in https://codepen.io/mvaneijgen/pen/EKMXdM?css-preprocessor=none with very little js too if you’re interested.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to achieve something close to what you are describing
with the @keyframe rule in CSS.

> https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes

Here is a very simplified version of a bouncing element

```css
    body {
        font: 1em sans-serif;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .stage {
        border-bottom: 3px solid #444;
        display: flex;
        height: 330px;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .box {
        align-self: flex-end;
        animation-duration: 2s;
        animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        background-color: #F44336;
        height: 200px;
        margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
        transform-origin: bottom;
        width: 200px;
    }
    .bounce-3 {
        animation-name: bounce-3;
        animation-timing-function: ease;
    }
    @keyframes bounce-3 {
        0%   { transform: translateY(0); }
        30%  { transform: translateY(-100px); }
        50%  { transform: translateY(0); }
        100% { transform: translateY(0); }
    }
```

```html
<h3>Add a Delay</h3>
<div class="stage">
    <div class="box bounce-3"></div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps